# How to use PHP code to detect browser in use as webview in-app MacOS?

Tags: php, webview, in-app

I want the user who opens the URL to use a webview (in-app MacOS).
If user use a normal browser, you must log in.

I use this code but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "your.app.id") {
echo 'YES';
} else {
echo 'NO';
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("location:login.php");
} else {
    echo "Wellcome " . $_SESSION['username'];
}
}
?>
```

your.app.id is product bundle identifier ??

My product bundle identifier is: `com.apple.test`

I open the url in the MacOS in-app but the result is always: `NO`

Comment: Do a print_r($_SERVER); and see what you are getting ... most servers do not contain the : $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] and then your code goes to login.php - which works by the way... so ....? I think you are looking for the wrong thing here.... for me it jumped to login.php isn't that what it should do?

Comment: Wait if you get NO and then nothing ... perhaps try removing the session_start() maybe your session is throwing an error